# definecolors option clash for package xcolor

Tags: color, packages, package-options

Have included the following in my style file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{andromeda}[2022/10/03 Andromeda Package]

\newif\ifCountryMaps
\CountryMapsfalse

\newif\ifScienTech
\ScienTechfalse

%% Options set boolean flags to true
\DeclareOption{CountryMaps}{\CountryMapstrue}
\DeclareOption{ScienTech}{\ScienTechtrue}

%% process the options before checking if the booleans are true
\ProcessOptions

%% Load Country Maps
\ifCountryMaps
  \RequirePackage{countriesofeurope}
\fi

%% Load Science and Technology Packages
\ifScienTech
  \RequirePackage{gensymb}
  \RequirePackage{wasysym}
  \RequirePackage{ifsym}
  \RequirePackage{textcomp}
  \RequirePackage{steinmetz}
  \RequirePackage{emf}
  \RequirePackage{fontawesome}
  \RequirePackage{utfsym}
  \RequirePackage{keystroke}
  \RequirePackage{svrsymbols}
\fi

\RequirePackage{etoolbox} % Programming tools

%% Deferred colours (with asterisk) for dvipsnames
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolors{Lavender}

%% Bold typeface
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}
\boldmath
```

And getting

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.110 \definecolors
                 {Lavender}
```

Comment: learn to make a complete example.

Comment: Some other package you load before doing `\usepackage[...]{xcolor}` already loads `xcolor` with different options.

Comment: If I have `\usepackage[CountryMaps]{andromeda}` followed by `\usepackage{userndr}` and `userndr` has `\usepackage{andromeda}`.  Would that be a problem?

Comment: I introspected a bit more and a problem seems to occur with this command `\newcommand{\teo-teora-pigment}{RawSienna}`.

Comment: @konmi no you have already loaded xcolor as egreg said above so you get an error from `\RequrePackage` I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided no test file but

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ScienTech]{andromeda}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

shows in the log:

```
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/utfsym/utfsym.sty
Package: utfsym 2022/04/17 Use TikZ to support icons from Unicode blocks

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-09-28 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-09-28 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count198
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
))
Package: l3keys2e 2022-06-22 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
```

showing `xcolor` is already loaded (with no options) via `utfym.sty`

So you get an option clash from

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
```

You could load `xcolor` with options earlier, or better load fewer potentially clashing packages,